# Python XMLRPC Nessus Error

Tags: python, xml-rpc, nessus

Anyone know why I am getting this error?

I am using http://code.google.com/p/nessusxmlrpc/wiki/HowTo

```
root@bt:~/NessusXMLRPC-0.21# python newnessusscan.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newnessusscan.py", line 6, in <module>
    scan = x.quickScan("MyXMLTestSCan", "192.168.1.100", "Internal Network Scan")
  File "/root/NessusXMLRPC-0.21/NessusXMLRPC.py", line 280, in quickScan
    if type(policies['policy']) is dict:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I tried passing an integer aswell but no such luck.

Attached is the code from the actual module which is having the problem:

```
 if type(policies['policy']) is dict:
            # There appears to be only one configured policy
            policy = policies['policy']
            if policy['policyName'] == policy_name:
                policy_id = policy['policyID']
```

Included is a link to the pastebin of newnessusscan.py:
http://pastebin.com/Bd2Zsw49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by an [error](http://code.google.com/p/nessusxmlrpc/issues/detail?id=4&thanks=4&ts=1325713085) in nessusxmlrpc-py.

You can apply the [patch](http://nessusxmlrpc.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=40000000&name=correct-quickscan.patch&token=enzhUARQPcE3u6QfZ8vP7-WGKQ8%3A1325713085983) or [download the corrected version](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rAvEAzQy) of `NessusXMLRPC.py`.

Comment: Thanks, phihag for your awesome python skills and taking the time to fix this bug.